# php rollover link and show image form databse that has same id

Tags: php, mysql, database, image, hover

I have a list of categories in a database that our echoed onto the page like so:

```
echo '<li><a href=#?id='.$row['category_id'] .' "> ' . $row['category_name'] . '</a></li>';
```

How would I echo that corresponding image(category_image) that is in the database when I hover over these links individually?

Do I hide a div and then have it appear on hover with the image inside? but then how do I transfer the id?

category_image is a path, not the actual image.

Comment: Are those images actually stored in the database or do you simply have the corresponding image path stored?

Comment: Then the answer is simple: Just output the image as well, hide it via CSS and show it on hover. No need to make a roundtrip to the server to fetch anything. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just output the image as well, hide it via CSS and show it on hover. No need to make a roundtrip to the server to fetch anything. ;-)